# Can blank target and range spells be considered valid for the teamwork feat share spells?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, feats

In a past question I asked if there was a way to cast personal spells on other creatures, and a solution was [given](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/154898/23058). It requires the teamwork feats [bonded mind](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/bonded-mind-teamwork) and [shared spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/share-spells-teamwork/), further enhanced by the spell [Coordinated Effort](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Coordinated%20Effort).

So the hard part was finished or so I thought. I was expecting a plethora of wonderful buff spells that are mediocre or situational to a caster, but a wonderful boon to martial and others. Searching d20 with "Target You" and "Range personal". This was further complicated by the fact that not all spells have the right information. Take [Bless](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bless) and [Detect Evil](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-evil) which both are missing range and target. Are these valid spells?

So the question is, spells whose description include you/the caster and without range/target allowed?

There is a [similar question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/95522/23058) I asked but was specifically about the normal familiar share spells ability.

Answer (score 4):

The Teamwork Feat [Share Spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/share-spells-teamwork/) says, in part

> You can cast a spell with a target of “you” on an ally as a touch spell, as per the share spells familiar ability, so long as the ally possesses the Bonded Mind feat.

The [Share Spells](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/familiar) familiar ability, in turn, says

> Share Spells: The wizard may cast a spell with a target of “You” on his familiar (as a touch spell) instead of on himself. A wizard may cast spells on his familiar even if the spells do not normally affect creatures of the familiar’s type (magical beast).

Unfortunately, as limiting as this seems, Share Spells (both feat and familiar ability) specifically only works with spells with a Target entry of You. Lacking a Target entry is not the same thing as a Target entry of You.

The Range entry of a spell also has nothing to do with whether or not it will work with Share Spells. As an example, the [Lead Blades](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/lead-blades/) spell has Range Personal, but the Target is Touch rather than You. Therefore, it would not work with Share Spells.

Neither of the examples you listed would work with Share Spells, even though they possibly seem like something that could. Both Bless and Detect Evil have an Area entry rather than a Target.

Comment: This answer is not acceptable because you linked to the familiar share spells and not the teamwork feat share spells that I linked to.

Comment: @Fering I don't believe there is any difference, but sure, I can include that.